# How to change warning setting?

Tags: r, warnings

I am trying to debug a function. I would like to display warnings when they occur but I don't understand how to change the warning settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set

```
options(warn=1)
```

---

Read more in `?options`

Answer (score 35):

It may be useful to specify

```
options(warn=2, error=recover)
```

As mentioned by @plannapus, `warn=2` will upgrade warnings to errors; `error=recover` will drop you into a debug/browser mode at the point where the warning (now upgraded to an error) occurred. (Use `options(warn=0, error=NULL)` to restore the original settings.)

Answer (score 12):

From the help page for `options` :

`warn`:
sets the handling of warning messages. If `warn` is negative all warnings are ignored. If `warn` is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns. If fewer than 10 warnings were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how many (max 50) were signalled. An object called `last.warning` is created and can be printed through the function `warnings`. If `warn` is one, warnings are printed as they occur. If `warn` is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors.

So `options(warn=1)` should print warnings as they occur.

Otherwise function `traceback()` (after an unidentified error) shows you which subroutine failed (more exactly "the sequence of calls that lead to the error").