# suppressing "masked" warnings outside libraries in R

Tags: r

I want to redefine `install.packages()` in my .Rprofile .  Specifically, I want to say

```
function(...) { stop("please run install.packages only with --no-init-file\n") }
```

unfortunately, it now annoys me on every startup with

```
The following object is masked _by_ '.GlobalEnv':

    install.packages
```

I have a few more functions like this...e.g., I want "source" to look at the file extension, and if it is .Rmd, I want it to run .Rmd through a filter.

none of these functions are in a library, so `warn.conflicts` does not work (and I want to turn the warnings back on lateron, too.)

how can I temporarily disable and enable these warnings?

Comment: Try `?options` though I think masking them isn't a great idea. I think it's options(warn=-1)specifically but not sure. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239428/how-to-change-warning-setting

Comment: Try wrapping in `suppressPackageStartupMessages()`

Comment: interestingly, I just learned that the warning message appeared not where I redefined `install.packages()`, but later when I loaded `library(utils)`.  so here, `warn.conflicts=FALSE` did work, after all.