# Rmarkdown - How to see the warnings when knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

So I am creating a html document with `html_document` in the yalm header with Rmarkdown. I push "knit" in Rstudio and the document gets created, but I get the following message at the end (in the Rmarkdown tab next to the Console and Terminal tabs):

```
Output created: version2_rapport.html
There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

But I don't know how to see the warnings... Where and how should I use `warnings()`? I have tried to type `warnings()` in the console but nothing happens.

My setup chunk is:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

```
````

I don't want messages in my output and I just want to see them i.e. they should not be included in my html file with my graphs etc.

Comment: As far as I know R will only store the last warning, which can be see with ``warnings()``. Since you put ``warning = FALSE`` I think one of the best  thing you can do is add ``warnings(file = "C:/path/to/a/txt/file/R-warnings.txt")`` in your script/R markdown so the last warning will be store on a ``.txt`` document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change warning setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239428/how-to-change-warning-setting)

Comment: @jay.sf: This is a Rmarkdown question the other is only about warnings.

Comment: @Gainz: It does not work..

Comment: @David I just tried on a R Markdown file and it worked, it gives me the last warning at this point in the document.

Comment: @Gainz: I am using a rstudio project so I just included ``warning(file =" warnings.txt")`` in the last chunk in the rmarkdown file..

Comment: @David Is R creating the .txt file?

Comment: @Gains. No and when I saw that R does not create it I created it myself. I also tried to close the file and open it again but nothing there...